# Error with Hash Table in c++

Tags: c++, list, vector, hashtable

I written a simple program for insert data in Hash Table and remove data from it with C++ language. My program error is: **undefined reference to 'HashTable::insert(int&)'**
How to fix this error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
```

I Create a template for give all variables.

```
template <typename HashedObj>
class HashTable {
public:
    explicit HashTable(int cusize = 101) {}

    bool contains(const HashedObj& x) const
    {
        auto& whichList = theLists[myhash(x)];
        return find(begin(whichList), end(whichList), x) != end(whichList);
    }

    void makeEmpty()
    {
        for (auto& thisList : theLists)
            thisList.clear();
    }

    bool insert(const HashedObj& x)
    {
        auto& whichList = theLists[myhash(x)];
        if (find(begin(whichList), end(whichList), x) != end(whichList))
            return false;
        whichList.push_back(x);

        //Rehash
        if (++currentSize > theLists.size())
            rehash();

        return true;
    }

    bool insert(HashedObj& x);
    bool remove(const HashedObj& x)
    {
        auto& whichList = theLists[myhash(x)];
        auto itr = find(begin(whichList), end(whichList), x);

        if (itr == end(whichList))
            return false;

        whichList.erase(itr);
        --currentSize;
        return true;
    }


private:
    vector<list<HashedObj>> theLists; //The array of Lists
    int currentSize;

    void rehash();
    size_t myhash(const HashedObj& x) const
    {
        static hash<HashedObj> hf;
        return hf(x) % theLists.size();
    }
};
```

In the main function i create a HashTable with int variable for example and insert 10 number to it but compiler has a error on **test = t.insert(i);** for insert function.

```
int main()
{
    HashTable<int> t;

    bool test;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        test = t.insert(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: tip: look at the paramenter of   <br>  bool insert(const HashedObj& x)

Comment: The easiest fix is to remove this declaration `bool insert(HashedObj& x);`. Alternatively, you may want to implement this overload. Finally, you can use `t.insert(std::move(i))` instead of `t.insert(i)` (you probably don't want to do that with non-trivial types, though). The options are listed in the order of my preference.

Comment: also, you need to `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: Then you'll have a problem with rehash being declared but not defined.

Comment: Is the second version of `insert` defined in a separate source file?  If so, what's its definition?  If not, why have you declared it?

Comment: @DietmarKühl thank you. All error was solved.
I write 'rehash()' thay way: 
'void rehash()
    {
        vector<list<HashedObj>> oldLists = theLists;
        theLists.resize(2 * theLists.size());
        for (auto& thisList : theLists)
            thisList.clear();

        currentSize = 0;
        for (auto& thisList : oldLists)
            for (auto& x : thisList)
                insert(std::move(x));
    }'
Did I write the correct rehash code?

Comment: @SamMarinelli 
No, I write this code from the _Data_ _Structures_ _And_ _Analysis_ _In_ _Cpp_ book. The second version of insert just written.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be two bool insert(params) functions in your code:

```
 bool insert(const HashedObj& x)
{
    auto& whichList = theLists[myhash(x)];
    if (find(begin(whichList), end(whichList), x) != end(whichList))
        return false;
    whichList.push_back(x);

    //Rehash
    if (++currentSize > theLists.size())
        rehash();

    return true;
}
```

and here:

```
bool insert(HashedObj& x);
```

Remove one of them.

Edit: As @DietmarKühl suggested, you should remove the second implementation.

Comment: Or implement both of them.

Comment: Removing the first overload doesn't solve the problem: after removing the first overload there would be no version of `insert()` with an implementation! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You declared two `insert` functions, the first one took a `const HashedObj&` parameter, the second one took a `HashedObj&` parameter.

`test = t.insert(i);`  `i` is a non-const variable here, so it matches the second insert function, but you didn't implement it.

It could work well if you remove the second `insert` declaration, because the compiler will convert `i` to a `const int&` type automaticlly.